# For loop skips duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

so I have a function which gets an array of objects from its parameter. In this example, there are 4 objects inside the array. The object contains the keys:

```
{ reportedBy: String, reason: String}
```

So the input array is:

```
[{reportedBy: "58dd0c8c23ffea1bb767614f", reason: "User insulted me"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c53faea1bb88379a", reason: "User insulted me"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c23ffea1bb767614f", reason: "User violated against FAQs"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c53fabb356fab", reason: "Uses a fake account"}]
```

So in this example, I have this object four times in the array. The keys can have duplicate values (like the IDs and the reason), so the `reportedBy` String can exist multiple times, just not together with the same `reason` String (That's because a user can report an item for every reason once). I just simply wanted to get all the 4 `reportedBy` and `reason` values. So I used a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
   console.log(object[i].reason);
   console.log(object[i].reportedBy);
}
```

`object` is the parameter of the function and contains the 4 objects. But the problem is that this only gives me back all the values **once** , and no duplicates. And I just don't get why, because this works:

```
console.log(object[0].reason);
console.log(object[1].reason);
console.log(object[2].reason);
console.log(object[3].reason);
```

I even tried to use a for loop that iterates from 0 to 4, but I still didn't get all the 4 values, only 3 because two are the same. Is it normal that the for loop skips duplicate values?

Comment: hey please give your javascript array having objects.

Comment: It hard to tell from the code you have provided, you should read the page [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for advice on formulating an answerable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me. Please see the snippet below for reference.

Please create snippet if it wont work for you. There is no issue with for loop.

It is also working for the array you have provided.

```js
array=[{reportedBy: "58dd0c8c23ffea1bb767614f", reason: "User insulted me"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c53faea1bb88379a", reason: "User insulted me"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c23ffea1bb767614f", reason: "User violated against FAQs"}, {reportedBy: "58dd0c8c53fabb356fab", reason: "Uses a fake account"}];


for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   console.log(array[i].reason);
   console.log(array[i].reportedBy);
}
```

Comment: I tried to create a snippet and you're right, that gave me the correct result...That's really weird...It's the same code I'm using but I just don't get the values..Everytime one is missing.  EDIT: Alllllright. I removed the for loop and copied yours to see if there was any mistake and now it is working o.O though there are no differences....Okay..Thank you anyway

Comment: ohh..thats really weird then

Comment: you are welcome. i am happy that atleast your problem is solved.keep up the good work